# Cancel drag if outside the application

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I keep searching all over the web but I can't find a way to restrict the scope of my drag to my application only.
Here is how I create the QDrag:

```
void                    mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (!(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton))
        return;
    if ((event->pos() - this->_dragStartPos).manhattanLength()
        < QApplication::startDragDistance())
        return;
    if (this->topLevelItemCount() < 1)
        return;

    QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;

    QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> list = this->selectedItems();
    QList<QUrl> urlList;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        QFileInfo fileToAdd(list.at(i)->data(0, CustomRole::Path).toString());

        QUrl add(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileToAdd.absoluteFilePath()));
        urlList.append(add);
    }

    mimeData->setUrls(urlList);
    drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
    drag->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/icons/grey-folder-opened"));

    Qt::DropAction dropAction = drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction);
    qDebug() << "finish dragging" << dropAction;
    delete drag;
}
```

There is the [targetChanged](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qdrag.html#targetChanged) signal but regarding Qt doc about the [exec](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qdrag.html#exec) function: "On Windows, the Qt event loop is blocked during the operation."

I also set all my other widget to disable the drag.
I try to override the `dragLeaveEvent` of the QMainWindow to ignore all of them but nah, nothing changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decide to create my own MIME type by adding that to the previous code:

```
[...]
QByteArray ba;
QDataStream ds(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
ds << urlList;

mimeData->setData("application/x-fc-windows", ba);
[...]
```

Work like a charm!